# How do I use data from sqlite to load a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How do I get all the values from my `sqlite` db to be displayed in a `UITableView`? My solution is only displaying one value. This is what I've tried:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)loadData {
    NSLog(@"display");
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    arrayOfperson = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM iApp"];
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_DB,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
             /*


             NSLog(@"%@", aname);


               Results * aRv= [[Results alloc] init];
              [aRv setName:aname];

               NSLog(@"%@", aname);


            [arrayOfperson addObject:aRv];
              NSLog(@"%@ values of array",arrayOfperson );
               return resultArray;
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"Not found");
                // return nil;
            }
            sqlite3_reset(statement);
        }
    }
  return arrayOfperson;
    //[self.arrayOfperson reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I remove a duplicate of the code block and cleaned up the grammar. There's an obvious error in the original code block that I left in place (there's a hanging comment open `/*` with no closing `*/`.

Comment: Why did you change your question completely?

Comment: Please do not edit questions to entirely change their meaning. This is unfair  to the users who have put their time into writing answers. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a good read of the [SQLite C Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) which sets out all the basic functions that you need to use to extract and insert data into an SQLite database.

It seems in your code that you are missing calls to `sqlite_column_x()` which is the function you use to extract data from a sqlite statement.

E.g.

```
while (sqlite_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) { // Could have while(sqlite_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) here...
    int myInt = sqlite_column_int(statement, 0); // Get int from column 1
    char *myText = sqlite_column_text(statement, 1); // Get text from column 2

    MyObj *obj = [MyObj objWithNum:myInt, text:[[NSString alloc] initWitCString:myText]];
    [myArray addObject:obj];
}
```

Also once you've finished with the `statement` you need to call `sqlite_finalize(statement)`. Likewise once you've finished with the database reference you need to call `sqlite_close(db);`

Comment: Where you've put `if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)` you need to replace with my code. But honestly read the docs first, otherwise you'll end up with no end of errors and leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, lets make this long but simple.

First, you'll have to get [FMDatabase](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) which is pretty much mandatory if you don't want to put a bullet in your head.

Once you've got that set up (which should take you about 1 or 2 hours if you're a beginner and it's your first time), you will create a class that deals with your database.

In that class, you'll have different loading/setting methods, one being the one you need now which will return an `NSMutableArray` of those objects you need.

```
NSMutableArray *myObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
FMResultSet *result = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM myTable"];
while ([result next]) {

    MyObj *obj      = [[MyObj alloc]init];
    obj.intNum      = [[results intForColumn:@"theNumColumn"]intValue];
    obj.nsnumberNum = [results intForColumn:@"theNSNumberColumn"];
    obj.theString   = [results stringForColumn:@"myString"];

    [myObjects addObject:obj];

}

return myObjects;
```

This will give you a reliable array of your custom object, which you can send to your tableview.

That array has to be given to the different `delegate` and `datasource` methods of your `tableview`, so it can know what to display, how to display it, and how much of it it should display.

From there on out it's cake. But I really strongly strongly suggest to use FMDB, it's a really good library that will make your life a **hundred times** easier than sqlite3.

(if you want your life to be a hundred times even more easier, I suggest you switch to core data)

But either way yeah :

- Class to manage database
- Method to return your array of custom obj
- Return that array into your display controller
- Eat Cookies.